# Maximo Spatial: Convert UTM to lat/long with Python 2.7.0 (using only the standard Python library)

Tags: python, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, utm

[Maximo Spatial](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSG2D3_7.6.0/com.ibm.spl.doc/welcome.html) is a work order management system in which I can write scripts in Python 2.7.0.

I want to write a Python 2.7.0 script in Maximo that will convert UTM coordinates to latitude/longitude decimal degree coordinates. Ideally, the transformation error would be less than 1 meter.

The catch:

It is only possible for me to use [**standard python libraries**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/) in my Python scripts in Maximo Spatial. I can't import external libraries.

Is there a way to convert UTM coordinates to lat/long using out-of-the-box Python 2.7.0?

Comment: The point with Maximo Spatial is that it integrates with ArcGIS Server, so you should have your spatial data stored in ArcSDE. Can't you use the toolset given in ArcGIS to do this?

Comment: @HavardMoe In most cases, yes, you're probably right. In my case, I'm  thinking about converting the values in the `WOSERVICEADDRESS`.`latitudex` & `longitudey` fields from UTM to Lat/Long. Specifically for the purpose of adding a calculated field to the `WORKORDER` or `WOSERVICEADDRESS` tables that is a Street View hyperlink. Or something like that. And I wondered if a robust/low-risk solution for converting the UTM to Lat/Long might be to just do it in a Jython automation script.

Comment: @HavardMoe Another option might be to convert the UTM coordinates to Lat/Long via a request to an ArcGIS geometry service.

Comment: For my records, this is how to convert UTM 17N to lat/long via a geometry service: `https://<my host name>/server/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer/project?inSR=26917&outSR=4326&geometries=682505.018593456%2C+4958027.56692643&transformation=&transformForward=true&vertical=false&f=json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a Python Library called [utm 0.5.0](https://pypi.org/project/utm/).

The `conversion.py` module in that library seems to do the trick.

I've modified the code by removing the reference to `numpy` and the custom `OutOfRangeError` library.

---

```
import math as mathlib

__all__ = ['to_latlon', 'from_latlon']

K0 = 0.9996

E = 0.00669438
E2 = E * E
E3 = E2 * E
E_P2 = E / (1.0 - E)

SQRT_E = mathlib.sqrt(1 - E)
_E = (1 - SQRT_E) / (1 + SQRT_E)
_E2 = _E * _E
_E3 = _E2 * _E
_E4 = _E3 * _E
_E5 = _E4 * _E

M1 = (1 - E / 4 - 3 * E2 / 64 - 5 * E3 / 256)
M2 = (3 * E / 8 + 3 * E2 / 32 + 45 * E3 / 1024)
M3 = (15 * E2 / 256 + 45 * E3 / 1024)
M4 = (35 * E3 / 3072)

P2 = (3. / 2 * _E - 27. / 32 * _E3 + 269. / 512 * _E5)
P3 = (21. / 16 * _E2 - 55. / 32 * _E4)
P4 = (151. / 96 * _E3 - 417. / 128 * _E5)
P5 = (1097. / 512 * _E4)

R = 6378137

ZONE_LETTERS = "CDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXX"

def in_bounds(x, lower, upper, upper_strict=False):
    if upper_strict and use_numpy:
        return lower <= mathlib.min(x) and mathlib.max(x) < upper
    elif upper_strict and not use_numpy:
        return lower <= x < upper
    elif use_numpy:
        return lower <= mathlib.min(x) and mathlib.max(x) <= upper
    return lower <= x <= upper

def mixed_signs(x):
    return use_numpy and mathlib.min(x) < 0 and mathlib.max(x) >= 0

def negative(x):
    if use_numpy:
        return mathlib.max(x) < 0
    return x < 0

def to_latlon(easting, northing, zone_number, zone_letter=None, northern=None, strict=True):

    if not zone_letter and northern is None:
        raise ValueError('either zone_letter or northern needs to be set')

    elif zone_letter and northern is not None:
        raise ValueError('set either zone_letter or northern, but not both')

    if strict:
        if not in_bounds(easting, 100000, 1000000, upper_strict=True):
            raise OutOfRangeError('easting out of range (must be between 100.000 m and 999.999 m)')
        if not in_bounds(northing, 0, 10000000):
            raise OutOfRangeError('northing out of range (must be between 0 m and 10.000.000 m)')

    if zone_letter:
        zone_letter = zone_letter.upper()
        northern = (zone_letter >= 'N')

    x = easting - 500000
    y = northing

    if not northern:
        y -= 10000000

    m = y / K0
    mu = m / (R * M1)

    p_rad = (mu +
             P2 * mathlib.sin(2 * mu) +
             P3 * mathlib.sin(4 * mu) +
             P4 * mathlib.sin(6 * mu) +
             P5 * mathlib.sin(8 * mu))

    p_sin = mathlib.sin(p_rad)
    p_sin2 = p_sin * p_sin

    p_cos = mathlib.cos(p_rad)

    p_tan = p_sin / p_cos
    p_tan2 = p_tan * p_tan
    p_tan4 = p_tan2 * p_tan2

    ep_sin = 1 - E * p_sin2
    ep_sin_sqrt = mathlib.sqrt(1 - E * p_sin2)

    n = R / ep_sin_sqrt
    r = (1 - E) / ep_sin

    c = _E * p_cos**2
    c2 = c * c

    d = x / (n * K0)
    d2 = d * d
    d3 = d2 * d
    d4 = d3 * d
    d5 = d4 * d
    d6 = d5 * d

    latitude = (p_rad - (p_tan / r) *
                (d2 / 2 -
                 d4 / 24 * (5 + 3 * p_tan2 + 10 * c - 4 * c2 - 9 * E_P2)) +
                 d6 / 720 * (61 + 90 * p_tan2 + 298 * c + 45 * p_tan4 - 252 * E_P2 - 3 * c2))

    longitude = (d -
                 d3 / 6 * (1 + 2 * p_tan2 + c) +
                 d5 / 120 * (5 - 2 * c + 28 * p_tan2 - 3 * c2 + 8 * E_P2 + 24 * p_tan4)) / p_cos

    return (mathlib.degrees(latitude),
            mathlib.degrees(longitude) + zone_number_to_central_longitude(zone_number))


def from_latlon(latitude, longitude, force_zone_number=None, force_zone_letter=None):

    if not in_bounds(latitude, -80.0, 84.0):
        raise OutOfRangeError('latitude out of range (must be between 80 deg S and 84 deg N)')
    if not in_bounds(longitude, -180.0, 180.0):
        raise OutOfRangeError('longitude out of range (must be between 180 deg W and 180 deg E)')

    lat_rad = mathlib.radians(latitude)
    lat_sin = mathlib.sin(lat_rad)
    lat_cos = mathlib.cos(lat_rad)

    lat_tan = lat_sin / lat_cos
    lat_tan2 = lat_tan * lat_tan
    lat_tan4 = lat_tan2 * lat_tan2

    if force_zone_number is None:
        zone_number = latlon_to_zone_number(latitude, longitude)
    else:
        zone_number = force_zone_number

    if force_zone_letter is None:
        zone_letter = latitude_to_zone_letter(latitude)
    else:
        zone_letter = force_zone_letter

    lon_rad = mathlib.radians(longitude)
    central_lon = zone_number_to_central_longitude(zone_number)
    central_lon_rad = mathlib.radians(central_lon)

    n = R / mathlib.sqrt(1 - E * lat_sin**2)
    c = E_P2 * lat_cos**2

    a = lat_cos * (lon_rad - central_lon_rad)
    a2 = a * a
    a3 = a2 * a
    a4 = a3 * a
    a5 = a4 * a
    a6 = a5 * a

    m = R * (M1 * lat_rad -
             M2 * mathlib.sin(2 * lat_rad) +
             M3 * mathlib.sin(4 * lat_rad) -
             M4 * mathlib.sin(6 * lat_rad))

    easting = K0 * n * (a +
                        a3 / 6 * (1 - lat_tan2 + c) +
                        a5 / 120 * (5 - 18 * lat_tan2 + lat_tan4 + 72 * c - 58 * E_P2)) + 500000

    northing = K0 * (m + n * lat_tan * (a2 / 2 +
                                        a4 / 24 * (5 - lat_tan2 + 9 * c + 4 * c**2) +
                                        a6 / 720 * (61 - 58 * lat_tan2 + lat_tan4 + 600 * c - 330 * E_P2)))

    if mixed_signs(latitude):
        raise ValueError("latitudes must all have the same sign")
    elif negative(latitude):
        northing += 10000000

    return easting, northing, zone_number, zone_letter

def latitude_to_zone_letter(latitude):
    # If the input is a numpy array, just use the first element
    # User responsibility to make sure that all points are in one zone
    if use_numpy and isinstance(latitude, mathlib.ndarray):
        latitude = latitude.flat[0]

    if -80 <= latitude <= 84:
        return ZONE_LETTERS[int(latitude + 80) >> 3]
    else:
        return None


def latlon_to_zone_number(latitude, longitude):
    # If the input is a numpy array, just use the first element
    # User responsibility to make sure that all points are in one zone
    if use_numpy:
        if isinstance(latitude, mathlib.ndarray):
            latitude = latitude.flat[0]
        if isinstance(longitude, mathlib.ndarray):
            longitude = longitude.flat[0]

    if 56 <= latitude < 64 and 3 <= longitude < 12:
        return 32

    if 72 <= latitude <= 84 and longitude >= 0:
        if longitude < 9:
            return 31
        elif longitude < 21:
            return 33
        elif longitude < 33:
            return 35
        elif longitude < 42:
            return 37

    return int((longitude + 180) / 6) + 1

def zone_number_to_central_longitude(zone_number):
    return (zone_number - 1) * 6 - 180 + 3
```

`print (to_latlon(671098, 4862979, 17, None, True, None))`

The output is: `(43.65770934705541, -79.3620332041889)` which is within my 1-meter error tolerance requirement.